# Align part questions in the exam class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

I wonder how I can align the `part` questions in the `exam` class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document} 

\newcommand\tegnboks{~\fbox{\phantom{$=$}}~}

\begin{questions}
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[4] Sett inn riktig symbol: $<$, $>$ eller $=$
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{parts}
        \part[1] \num{2,6}\tegnboks\num{2,43}
        \part[1] \num{4,16}\tegnboks\num{3,86}
        \part[1] \num{8,45}\tegnboks\num{8,732}
        \part[1] \num{5.7}\tegnboks\num{5.699}
    \end{parts}
\end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

With the example above the result is

[image]

which doesn't look good. How can I align the `part`s around the `\tegnboks` command while keeping (a), (b), ... left aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the argument to the left of the `\tegnboks` into a box (default width same as `0.00`), using `\snum`.  You can pass an optional string argument to `\snum` to resize the width of the box (to the string width). I also right-aligned the matter to the left of the `\tegnbokx`, which can easily be redefined to a different alignment, if you prefer.

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\snum[2][0.00]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}][r]{\num{#2}}}
\begin{document} 

\newcommand\tegnboks{~\fbox{\phantom{$=$}}~}

\begin{questions}
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[4] Sett inn riktig symbol: $<$, $>$ eller $=$
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{parts}
        \part[1] \snum{2,6}\tegnboks\num{2,43}
        \part[1] \snum{4,16}\tegnboks\num{3,86}
        \part[1] \snum{8,45}\tegnboks\num{8,732}
        \part[1] \snum{5.7}\tegnboks\num{5.699}
    \end{parts}
\end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know the longest or desired part of equations, you can make an appropriate box (the second part is modified twice). Here left-hand part is left aligned.

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document} 

\newcommand\tegnboks{~\fbox{\phantom{$=$}}~}

\newlength\dlug
\settowidth{\dlug}{4.16}
\def\MB#1{\makebox[\dlug][l]{#1}}

\begin{questions}
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[4] Sett inn riktig symbol: $<$, $>$ eller $=$
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{parts}
        \part[1] \num{2,6}\tegnboks\num{2,43}
        \part[1] \num{4,16}\tegnboks\num{3,86}
        \part[1] \num{8,45}\tegnboks\num{8,732}
        \part[1] \num{5.7}\tegnboks\num{5.699}
    \end{parts}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
 \begin{parts}
        \part[1] \MB{\num{2,6}}\tegnboks\num{2,43}
        \part[1] \MB{\num{4,16}}\tegnboks\num{3,86}
\settowidth{\dlug}{4.16123}
        \part[1] \MB{\num{8,45}}\tegnboks\num{8,732}
        \part[1] \MB{\num{5.7}}\tegnboks\num{5.699}
    \end{parts}
\end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]